# Create a batch file to run an .exe with one argument

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file that a user can run ... in the batch file I want to run an exe with one argument.

Here is what I have today:

```
@echo off
c:\
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\App Location\App34\"
start HelperSetup.exe -arg
```

When I run that it opens up the cmd window and says the path cannot be found but i know for 100% it is the correct path.

I have tried to also pass in the string in a one line but no joy

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\App Location\App34\HelperSetup.exe -arg"
```

Comment: Remove `@echo off` for now to trace what is happening. Execute `explorer "C:\Program Files(x86)\App Location\App34\"` on the command line to double-check the path

Comment: resolved ... will edit

Comment: A much simpler approach is to use `start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\App Location\App34\" HelperSetup.exe -arg`. This way you don't need to change the drive and you don't need the cd command at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to also pass in the string in a one line but no joy

When you want to also pass in the string in a one line you need to set the closing quote at the end of the path like this:

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\App Location\App34\HelperSetup.exe" -arg
```

A much simpler approach for your batch script is to use the following command sequence

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\App Location\App34\" HelperSetup.exe -arg
```

This way, you don't need to change the drive and the cd command at all.